# Will the multicast address be conflict?

Tags: networking, multicast

I am trying with multicast. I am using 225.3.4.5 as server group, I just wonder if another guy use the same address, how will my packet be delivered?

Comment: "_I am using 225.3.4.5 as server group_" That is a RESERVED group that you are not allowed to use. You should probably use a group in the `239.0.0.0/8` Organization-Local Scope. See the _[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)_.

Comment: even I am using 239.0.0.0/8, will there is a conflict happen? Say another guy also use the same group?

Comment: All the multicast does is let a host listen for traffic sent to that group. Hosts receive traffic for their own address from multiple sources, and it works the same way for a multicast address. The process listening for traffic on that multicast address will receive traffic from both hosts. With `16,777,216` possible multicast groups in the `239.0.0.0/8` Organization-Local Scope, it is unlikely that you would even have two using the same multicast group.

Comment: Since multicast group can across router, I am just wondering if my traffic will be intercept by hacker if they set up the same group?

Comment: Multicast can only cross routers if all the routers in the path have multicast routing enabled, using the same multicast routing protocol. That is not done on the public Internet, so you can't route multicast on the public Internet. To cross the public Internet, you must use a tunnel to route multicast from one site to another.

Comment: OK, then I think I am pretty safe to use multicast, right?

Comment: Lots of thing already use multicast on your network. For example, spanning tree uses multicast on your switches, IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, so it heavily uses multicast, and many routing protocols, e.g. OSPF use multicast.